# how to add a style to a container depending on which routerLink finds me at that moment

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular-routing

my menu:

```
<header class="box-one"  >
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu-horizontal">
      <li><a  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/init">init</a></li>
      <li><a  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="plataform">Plataforms</a></li>
      <li><a  routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="About us">About us</a></li>
      <li><a  routerLinkActive="active"  routerLink="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

and I have this function that dims(transparent) and returns the background color of the header

```
 funScroll() {
    var header = document.querySelector(".box-one")
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
      header!.classList.toggle("arriba", window.scrollY < 800);
      header!.classList.toggle("abajo", window.scrollY > 500);
    })
  }
```

but I want only the home page to do that in the hearder and the other pages just darken.

this code didn't work.

```
private router = inject(Router)


  constructor() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event.url); // ruta actual
        this.currentRoute = event.url;


        if (event.url === "/inicio") {

          this.funScroll()
        } else {

        }
        if (event.url === "/plataforma") {

          var header = document.querySelector(".box-one");
          header!.classList.add('abajo');
        }


      }
    });
  }
```

I already gave up on this code.